# Passing parameters to a pipeline's fit() in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a sklearn pipeline with `PolynomialFeatures()` and `LinearRegression()` in series. My aim is to fit data to this using different `degree` of the polynomial features and measure the score. The following is the code I use -

```
steps = [('polynomials',preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures()),('linreg',linear_model.LinearRegression())]
pipeline = pipeline.Pipeline(steps=steps)

scores = dict()
for i in range(2,6):
    params = {'polynomials__degree': i,'polynomials__include_bias': False}
    #pipeline.set_params(**params)
    pipeline.fit(X_train,y=yCO_logTrain,**params)
    scores[i] = pipeline.score(X_train,yCO_logTrain)

scores
```

I receive the error - `TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'degree'`.

Why is this error thrown even though the parameters are named in the format `<estimator_name>__<parameter_name>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [`sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline` documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html):

> **fit_paramsdict of string -> object Parameters passed to the fit method of each step, where each parameter name is prefixed such that
> parameter p for step s has key s__p.

This means that the parameters passed this way are directly passed to `s` step `.fit()` method. If you check [PolynomialFeatures documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), `degree` argument is used in construction of the `PolynomialFeatures` object, not in its `.fit()` method.

If you want to try different hyperparameters for estimators/transformators within a pipeline, you could use [GridSearchCV as shown here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). Here's an example code from the link:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('select', SelectKBest()),
    ('model', calibrated_forest)])
param_grid = {
    'select__k': [1, 2],
    'model__base_estimator__max_depth': [2, 4, 6, 8]}
search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, cv=5).fit(X, y)
```